# upload csv file containing million values to a particular column in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, bulkinsert

Database: `MySQL`

CSV file having around million records like the following:

```
234546,345674,464368,563236,684269,707853,...
```

Data should get added into db in following manner:

```
id|number|status| ...
-----------------------
 1|234546| ...  | ...
 2|345674| ...  | ...
 3|464368| ...  | ...
 4|563236| ...  | ...
 5|684269| ...  | ...
 6|707853| ...  | ...
```

I've found some ways of uploading a csv file when the csv file contains values for each column. But here in my case, I have to insert values to a particular column. What is the efficient way of doing this in java?

Comment: read csv line by line , write in to database line by line simultaneously , whats the prob ??

Comment: you mean you want to insert the exact file in the database? or just the path?

Comment: I want to insert the values in the db. While reading line by line and inserting line by line, it's taking around 15-20 min. for about a million records, I want to fasten this process. I'm getting this file through a servlet(user is uploading this file).

Comment: why dont just let it there inside the csv? if you want to insert or update particular column later then just read it line by line. It won't take times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to load data from file is [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). Try it this way

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv'
IGNORE -- use this if you have duplicate numbers in the file and UNIQUE constraint defined on `number` column
INTO TABLE table1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY ','
(number)
```

Let's try it

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Table1
    -> (
    ->   `id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
    ->   `number` int, 
    ->   `status` varchar(32)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE table1
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY ','
    -> (number);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from table1;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | number | status |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | 234546 | NULL   |
|  2 | 345674 | NULL   |
|  3 | 464368 | NULL   |
|  4 | 563236 | NULL   |
|  5 | 684269 | NULL   |
|  6 | 707853 | NULL   |
+----+--------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**UPDATE:** If you need to do some basic transformations or validations you can use `SET` clause along with user variables

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE table1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY ','
(@number)
SET number = CONCAT('prefix', @number)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's works very fine. But there is a problem while uploading the numbers if the column is indexed with a unique constraint, it adds duplicate values than also. How can we prevent that?

Comment: @Pankaj You're very welcome :). if you have duplicate numbers in the file and `UNIQUE` constraint defined on `number` column in your table use `IGNORE` clause. MySQL will treat errors as warnings and skip such rows. See updated answer.

Comment: 1 more thing. can i do manipulations while inserting text? i mean if i want to prefix something to the number or allow only last 3 digits to go into db, can that be done with this method?

Comment: @Pankaj Yes you can do some basic transformations/validations by using `SET` clause and user variables. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make `id` field AUTO_INCREMENT.
2. Set default values for other fields.
3. Use LOAD DATA INFILE to insert only one field - `number`, and set ',' as a line separator.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the LOAD DATA INFILE technology in MySQL.

for eg:

```
String path = "o.csv";
                String esquel = " LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE " + path +
                            " INTO TABLE mytable" +
                            " LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'";

statement.executeUpdate(esquel);
```

Rewrite the query correctly for your requirement. This do a direct load instead of using the JAVA JDBC API for inserting.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using bash shell script to handle this problem directly, instead of using Java. We may follow the steps below:

First generate SQL statements to insert:

> tr ',' '\n' < text.csv  | grep -v "^[ \t]*$" | awk '{print "INSERT
>   INTO YOURTABLE (id, number) VALUES ("NR ", " $1 ")"}' > insert.sql

- tr ',' '\n' < text.csv  : Replace ',' with the newline '\n';
- grep -v "^[ \t]*$" : Remove empty lines;
- awk ... > insert.sql : Add the SQL keywords into it.

The result may look like this:

> INSERT INTO YOURTABLE (id, number) VALUES (1, 234546)
>
> INSERT INTO YOURTABLE (id, number) VALUES (2, 345674)
>
> INSERT INTO YOURTABLE (id, number) VALUES (3, 464368)
>
> INSERT INTO YOURTABLE (id, number) VALUES (4, 563236)

Then execute these SQL insertions:

> ```
> mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOST < insert.sql
> ```